# (F#) Using MathNet.Numerics in Visual Studio Professional 2013

Tags: f#

I'm trying to use MathNet.Numerics in an F# project, and I can't seem to add it as a dependency. If I go to "Manage NuGet Packages," I can install it, but I can't add it to my References; IntelliSense and the compiler then both tell me that it can't find the package MathNet.

Comment: Could You give more details: What version of Visual Studio? What exactly do You mean when saying cannot add to references? Nuget shall add it to references automatically. I am able to add MathNet in f# project via nuGet without any issues in VS 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved - I had installed MathNet Numerics instead of MathNet Numerics for F#. Also I might not have saved my project before closing it.